# what's google cloud pub/sub latency

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have an application that requires really low latency (real time game).
Currently in my solution it takes less than 2 milliseconds for a message to route to from the client front-end server to the destination server.

Does anybody know how much time will it take in Google Cloud Pub/Sub to route a message from one server to another?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

While Cloud Pub/Sub's end-to-end latency at the 99.9th percentile is sufficient for many applications--including some using it for real-time interaction, 2ms is lower than what the system can currently promise. We have thus far prioritized high throughput and strong delivery guarantees. End-to-end latency is also highly dependent on the rate at which a subscriber issues pull requests. A subscriber should always have at least a few open pull requests if throughput and/or latency are important. We do aim to significantly reduce out intra-region latencies but at the moment Cloud Pub/Sub cannot guarantee 2ms intra-region latencies at the 99.9th percentile.

Comment: So what is the lowest google pub/sub can guarantee? we see latencies from 300ms to ~1.2s

Comment: And... what is Google's best product to answer the OP?  Yes, the OP asked about pubsub, but his _real_ question, as I read it, was, "what is the best off-the-shelf GCP option for delivering messages with < 2ms guarantee?"